# In Scala, can a program finishes/exits if one of his Future val is unfinished?

Tags: scala, future

A simple example to illustrate the problem:

1 - Here, does the program exits after the future is completed ?

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

  val future: Future[Unit] = myFunction()

}
```

2 - If not, should I had an `Await` to guarantee that the future terminates?

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

  val future: Future[Unit] = myFunction()
  Await.result(future, Inf)

}
```

Comment: You are totally right, nothing prevents me to test it. However, what I expect by answering this question, is not a simple yes/no answer, but some explanations :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading [this](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) about Futures/Promises in Scala, the point is: it is **not** the Future that is about *concurrency*.

Meaning: what prevents the JVM from *exiting* are running threads. Coming from there: unless *something* in your code creates an additional thread that somehow prevents the JVM from exiting, your `main()` should simply end.

Futures are a mean to interact with content which becomes available at some later point in time. You should rather look into your code base to determine what kind of threading comes in place, and for example if some underlying thread pool executor is configured regarding the threads it is using.

Comment: But then doesnt it mean that one needs to use Await to ensure that Future is completed, which basically means blocking, just like Java Future.get.

Answer (score 2):

A `future` is value that is returned after executing a piece of task independently by a new thread(mostly) spawned by the another thread(say main).

To answer your question **Yes** the main thread will exit even if any `future` is still under execution.

```
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
object TestFutures  extends  App{

  def doSomeOtherTask = {
    Thread.sleep(1000) //do some task of 1 sec
    println("Completed some task by "+Thread.currentThread().getName)
  }

  def returnFuture : Future[Int]= Future{
    println("Future task started "+Thread.currentThread().getName)
    Thread.sleep(5000) //do some task which is 5 sec
    println("Future task completed "+Thread.currentThread().getName)
    5
  }
    val x = returnFuture //this takes 5 secs
    doSomeOtherTask  // ~ 1 sec job
    println(x.isCompleted)
    doSomeOtherTask // ~ 2 sec completed
    println(x.isCompleted)
    doSomeOtherTask // ~ 3 sec completed
    println(x.isCompleted)
    println("Future task is still pending and main thread have no more lines to execute")
}
```

### Output:-

```
Future task started scala-execution-context-global-11
Completed some task by main
false
Completed some task by main
false
Completed some task by main
false
Future task is still pending and main thread have no more lines to execute
```